# Javascript Form Validation (Return Issue)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, return

There is a problem with my Javascript form validation where I'm trying to return true or false values but it is not working.It only returns the first if/else statements (whether it is true or false) and from there it doesn't work.Once you see the javascript code, you should understand what I am trying to do.

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    name = $("#name").val(); //name input
    age = $("#age").val(); //age input
    sex = $("#sex").val(); // sex input

    if(name.match(/(\w)\s(\w)/)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
            $('.form-row:first-child').css('border','1px solid red');
            return false;
    }

    if (age < 0 || age > 130 || isNaN(age)) {
            $('.form-row:nth-child(2)').css('border','1px solid red');
            return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

        if (sex == "male" || sex == "Male" || sex == "female" || sex == "Female"){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $('.form-row:nth-child(3)').css('border','1px solid red');
            return false;
        }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will break out of the function. Instead, set a flag and return that flag at the end.

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    returnFlag = false
    name = $("#name").val(); //name input
    age = $("#age").val(); //age input
    sex = $("#sex").val(); // sex input

    if(name.match(/(\w)\s(\w)/)){
        returnFlag = true;
    }
    else {
            $('.form-row:first-child').css('border','1px solid red');
            returnFlag = false;
    }

    if (age < 0 || age > 130 || isNaN(age)) {
            $('.form-row:nth-child(2)').css('border','1px solid red');
            returnFlag = false;
    }
    else {
        returnFlag = true;
    }

        if (sex == "male" || sex == "Male" || sex == "female" || sex == "Female"){
            returnFlag = true;
        }
        else {
            $('.form-row:nth-child(3)').css('border','1px solid red');
            returnFlag = false;
        }

    return returnFlag;
  });
```

Comment: The problem now is that the first *if..else* might set the flag to false, but the next may reset it to true…

Comment: You're right, I didn't even think about that. I suppose actually returning false where returnFlag == false would work depending on the use case.

Comment: *returnFlag* can be initialised to *true*, then not set when tests past, just set to *false* if tests fail. ;-)